# Oracle SQL how to get the group by columns along with other selected columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query :

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) TotalCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' THEN 1 END) ApartmentCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' THEN 1 END) VillaCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'STUDIO' THEN 1 END) StudioCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'DUPLEX' THEN 1 END) DuplexCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) ApartmentCountActiveTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) VillaCountActiveTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'STUDIO' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) StudioCountActiveTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'DUPLEX' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) DuplexCountActiveTotal
FROM CMT WHERE COND1 = COND1 AND COND2=COND2
```

Now , along with the above select values in the query I wanted the below results to also come

```
(SELECT ROUND (SUM(RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT)*0.05) ApartmentMuncipalFee FROM CMT T WHERE COND1 = COND1 
       AND T.unit_usage_type_descr_e = 'RESIDENTIAL' 
       AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT'
       GROUP BY T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E)

       (SELECT ROUND (SUM(RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT)*0.05) VillaMuncipalFee FROM CMT T WHERE COND1 = COND1 
       AND T.unit_usage_type_descr_e = 'RESIDENTIAL' 
       AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA'
       GROUP BY T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E) VillaMuncipalFee
```

Kindly need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them into `SELECT` statement :

```
SELECT . . . ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.unit_usage_type_descr_e = 'RESIDENTIAL' AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' THEN RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT * 0.05 ELSE 0 END) AS ApartmentMuncipalFee, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN T.unit_usage_type_descr_e = 'RESIDENTIAL' AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' THEN RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT * 0.05 ELSE 0 END) AS VillaMuncipalFee
FROM CMT
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `aggregate` function, add an extra condition in the `count` and remove the condition from the `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) TotalCount,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' THEN 1 END) ApartmentCountTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' THEN 1 END) VillaCountTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'STUDIO' THEN 1 END) StudioCountTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'DUPLEX' THEN 1 END) DuplexCountTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) ApartmentCountActiveTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) VillaCountActiveTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'STUDIO' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) StudioCountActiveTotal,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COND2 = COND2 AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'DUPLEX' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) DuplexCountActiveTotal,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN UNIT_USAGE_TYPE_DESCR_E = 'RESIDENTIAL' AND UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E = 'APARTMENT' THEN RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT END) * 0.05) AS APARTMENTMUNCIPALFEE,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN UNIT_USAGE_TYPE_DESCR_E = 'RESIDENTIAL' AND UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E = 'VILLA' THEN RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT END) * 0.05) AS VILLAMUNCIPALFEE
FROM CMT
WHERE COND1 = COND1; -- removed COND2 = COND2 and added in the all count
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WITH` clause to create temp tables.

````
WITH TAB1 AS (
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) TotalCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' THEN 1 END) ApartmentCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' THEN 1 END) VillaCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'STUDIO' THEN 1 END) StudioCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'DUPLEX' THEN 1 END) DuplexCountTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) ApartmentCountActiveTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) VillaCountActiveTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'STUDIO' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) StudioCountActiveTotal,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'DUPLEX' AND T.TENANCY_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 END) DuplexCountActiveTotal
FROM CMT WHERE COND1 = COND1 AND COND2=COND2
) , TAB2 AS 
(SELECT ROUND (SUM(RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT)*0.05) ApartmentMuncipalFee FROM CMT T WHERE COND1 = COND1 
       AND T.unit_usage_type_descr_e = 'RESIDENTIAL' 
       AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'APARTMENT'
       GROUP BY T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E), TAB3 AS 
       (SELECT ROUND (SUM(RENTAL_VALUE_PER_UNIT)*0.05) VillaMuncipalFee FROM CMT T WHERE COND1 = COND1 
       AND T.unit_usage_type_descr_e = 'RESIDENTIAL' 
       AND T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E  = 'VILLA'
       GROUP BY T.UNIT_TYPE_DESCR_E) 

select * from TAB1, TAB2, TAB3
       ```
````